# Navigation bar fixed for hide and show issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have created navigation bar below the content:

**The Players** - sidebarheading

**Law 1.1** - subsidebar

**1.2.1** - subsubsidebar

```
<div class="sidebar">
   <p class="sidebarheading" id="topic1">The Players</p>
   <div class="parentsidebar" id="subtopic-3">
      <p class="subsidebar" style="display: block;">Law 1.1</p>
   </div>
   <div class="parentsidebar" id="subtopic-5">
      <p class="subsidebar" style="display: block;">Law 1.2</p>
   </div>
   <p class="subsubsidebar" id="subtopic-5" style="display: block;">1.2.1</p>
   <p class="subsubsidebar" id="subtopic-5" style="display: block;">1.2.2</p>
   <p class="subsubsidebar" id="subtopic-5" style="display: block;">1.2.3</p>
   <p class="subsubsidebar" id="subtopic-5" style="display: block;">1.2.4</p>
   <p class="subsubsidebar" id="subtopic-5" style="display: block;">1.2.5</p>
   <p class="subsubsidebar" id="subtopic-5" style="display: block;">1.2.6</p>
   <p class="subsubsidebar" id="subtopic-5" style="display: block;">1.2.7</p>
   <div class="parentsidebar" id="subtopic-6">
      <p class="subsidebar" style="display: block;">Law 1.3</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

If I click 'The Players' button show the 'Law 1.1' section, the next 'Law 1.1' section click show the 'subsubsidebar' sections

I'm having a problem with the navigation bar in the hide and show not working properly. I've tried alot but nothing seems to work. I have not share with my CSS file and JS file.

Please help me **CSS** and **JS** file

Note: All data will come from json.

I have created a fiddle this is my issue: [jsfiddle.net/2fzd5o1q](http://jsfiddle.net/2fzd5o1q/)

Comment: Can you create a fiddle so we can see the issue more clearly

Comment: I have created a fiddle this is my issue: https://jsfiddle.net/2fzd5o1q/

Comment: Id must be unique, for the start...